# Need help identifying this connector

Tags: identification, connector

I bought an ortur rotary and the motor burnt.  I replaced it but the cables are different. Please identify this so I can find a cross over for the rotary.

[image: connector]

Comment: do you know why the motor burnt? maybe you new motor will burn when you plug it in.

Answer (score 8):

Its street name is a [DuPont connector](https://www.google.com/search?q=DuPont+connector&client=firefox-b-1-d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXtJjxn570AhVUnWoFHX2vDscQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1600&bih=716&dpr=1), even though they are not made by Dupont. The pitch is 0.1" (2.54 mm).

Comment: so I can look up a 2.54 mm Dupont Connection to whatever the other connection is and find an adapter that way?

Comment: @user yes, that, or just cut and splice the cables.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a socket housing designed to accept pin headers. Most of the major connector manufacturers make them, but they all have different names for them. The pitch is most likely 2.54mm though other pitches exist.

The eBay/Alibaba crowd call them "Dupont connectors", but don't expect that name to turn up anything at more professional suppliers.

My technique when shopping for said connectors is to go into the "wire to board connectors" section on the suppliers site, set parametrics on the pin pitch, pin count, row count etc and then look through the pictures to find the right one.

Finally remember just because something has the same connector, doesn't mean it has the same pinout.

Comment: Sadly, this perfectly describes the situation as is. Unfortunately (been there, done that, got burned) there are a few more things to watch out for. F.e. I was browsing the catalogue of TE Connectivity looking for just this type of connector, and there is a multitude of somewhat matching types. Many of those unfortunately are made for machine crimping or, worst, have a slightly larger pin diameter which means that the connector won't hold on its own when placed onto regular pin headers. (ctd.)

Comment: I believe the best course for OP is to stick with amazon and not even try to find the correct match at f.e. mouser or the like. Amazon stuff is very generic and has a good chance of working if your additional advice is taken into consideration.